# Update last entry in MySQL using python(flask)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask

I am trying to create a function that updates the first name where the id is the last in the database. This needs to be dynamic so that when a new row has been generated, it will update the row of the first name containing the highest id.

I have tried two approaches, one which uses `SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` in my code below and another that uses `SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable`. Both approaches failed and came back with the following error message.

`MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting`

Here is the function in service one which contains the error:

```
@app.route("/edit_first_name", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def edit_first_name():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        """
        Collect first name from service 4.
        Amend the first name of last entry in database and display entry in table.
        """
        updated_first_name = requests.get("http://service_4:5003/first_name")
        first_name = updated_first_name.text
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('UPDATE names SET first_name = %s WHERE id = (SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)', (first_name))
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM names')
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        names = []

        for row in rows: 
            names.append(row)

        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close() 
        return render_template("layout.html", first_name = first_name, title = "Name Generator", names = names)
```

Here is the code for service 4 which generates the first name:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/first_name", methods = ['GET'])
def first_name():
    list = ["Valeria","Perla", "Elisabeth", "Joanna", "Jordan"]
    list += ["Violet", "Conor", "Whitney", "Ethen", "Ronan", "Selina", "Simone"]
    return list[random.randrange(12)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port = 5001, host = "0.0.0.0", debug = True)
```

Comment: Sorting to get the max Is not efficient.

Comment: Also note that in a multiuser environment, you could end up updating the wrong row.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a subselect in an update that selects from the same table that's being updated.  You would need to obtain the ID in a separate query, which will make the concurrency issues you already have (the risk of updating the wrong row) worse.

Overall you mostly need a different fundamental approach that makes what you're doing better-defined.